# 403 Forbidden - Mac Local Host

Tags: html, macos, apache, localhost, mamp

I am attempting to set up an AMP stack in order to do some basic web design with HTML 5, PHP, CSS, Apache, etc.  I have done this on a PC but I am having trouble setting it up on my new Mac.  I am trying to follow these steps (http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-osx-10-11-el-capitan/) but at the end of the first set of instructions I can't get the files to show and am getting a 403 error.  Can someone please point me in the right direction or give me a good resource. Thank you.

Here is my current permissions on the file:

```
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   96 Jan 10 13:39 Guest.conf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  132 Jan 20 15:52 username.conf
```

Comment: Is Guest your username or username is your username on your Mac?
You're suppoused to create configuration file according to your username on your Mac. (e.g. `dvLden.conf`)

Just checking if you did it correctly. That guide is working fine.

Comment: @dvLden I have redacted my actual username and used the word username instead.  But my username is what I used to create the configuration file.  Thanks anyway.  The guide works until I try to access the directory.

Answer (score 0):

The way I found easiest was to do the following:

```
cd /filepath/to/thing/you/want; php -S localhost:8000
```

and then visit localhost:8000 on your computer.

Hoped this helps, as this is my first answer on StackOverflow.

Comment: That answer does not resolve OP's problem. But it would be useful to explain your command...

Comment: I'm still a little lost to be honest.  Can you explain how that applies please?

Comment: @computersciencestudent This simulates a PHP server on your computer at the directory. You put it in terminal, and visit localhost:8000 and PHP is running.